# How to store errors in PLY yacc

Tags: python, yacc, ply

I am using ply.yacc for building a parser, and I'm interesting in storing all syntax errors in a list. I want something like this:

```py
parser = yacc.yacc()
parser.errors = []
parser.parse(program)
print(parser.errors) # do something with parser.errors
```

The problem is that when I define the rule for handling error

```py
def p_error(p):
    ...
```

I don't how to access the parser instance, so I can append the error to my list. For the lexer, I used **ply.lex** and solved this problem because the token **t** which is passed as argument in the rule definition has a reference to the lexer.

```py
def t_error(t):
  t.lexer.error.append(LexicographicError(t.lineno, t.value[0]))
```

Is there any way to do something similar with **yacc** parser???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `p_error` is usually a token (so the prototype would be better written `def p_error(t):`), so you could add the errors to the same list as you used in your lexer. But that's not ideal; first, because that's an odd place to keep the errors (both lexical and syntactical), and second because sometimes the argument to `p_error` is `None` (when the error occurs at the end of input).

A better solution is to make the parser a class rather than a global, which is explained rather briefly in the Ply documentation (mostly by reference to the section on making the lexer a class). Normally, you would build the parser in the Parser class's `__init__` method, saving it as `self.parser`. Then all of the `p_*` member functions take a `self` argument, as with any class function, and you can store the error list as a member attribute. (You can get at the `parser` using `self.parser` but I think keeping the list of errors in the object instance itself is cleaner than adding it to the parser instance.)